# Compound relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm playing around with neo4j - seeing what I can and can't do with it before suggesting it for something serious. One thing that I'm trying to work out is if you can have what I'm calling a compound relationship.

In my playing, I'm doing a family tree - it seems an ideal fit. I'm wanting to express that a life event occurred between two people - getting married for example - and where it happened. The MARRIED_TO relationship between two PERSON nodes is easy. I'm struggling with the relationship to the PLACE node though.

In my head, it seems that what I really want is a relationship that goes from the PLACE node to the MARRIED_TO relationship, and I don't think that's possible.

Alternatively, I could see the MARRIED_TO relationship going between three nodes, but that not only doesn't feel right but also isn't possible.

The best i can see to do is either have a EVENT node representing the marriage, which feels clunky, or else have relationships from both PERSON nodes to the PLACE, which is then duplication of data.

Is there a proper way of managing this kind of data? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider "Marriage" being a vital part of your domain. Anything being an entity deserves a separate node - so "Marriage" (or Event) becomes a node. That node then can be connected to the two people and the location.

Comment: That was the best I could come up with. It then ends up with all of the properties being on nodes and not relationships, and the relationships simply connecting things together, but it does work. Technically it does allow for incorrect links - e.g. a third person - but that might be OK and can be handled in business logic otherwise.